# Counting data within ranges in csv

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7

I have some data which I need to break down into manageable chunks. With the following data I need to count the number of times x occurs in column 11 with column 7 being a 1 and how many times the number x occurs in column 11. I need to put them into the first line of a csv. After that I need to count the same thing but with column 11 being the following brackets:

0

">0 but <0.05"

">0.05 but <0.10"

">0.1 but <0.15... all the way up to 1.00"

All of these would ideally be appended to the same new.csv i.e. not the main data csv

Some example raw data that fits the above description (please note a lot of the brackets will contain no data. In which case they would need to return 0,0:

```
01/01/2002,Data,class1,4,11yo+,4,1,George Smith,0,0,x
01/01/2002,Data,class1,4,11yo+,4,2,Ted James,0,0,x
01/01/2002,Data,class1,4,11yo+,4,3,Emma Lilly,0,0,x
01/01/2002,Data,class1,4,11yo+,4,5,George Smith,0,0,x
02/01/2002,Data,class2,4,10yo+,6,4,Tom Phillips,0,0,x
02/01/2002,Data,class2,4,10yo+,6,2,Tom Phillips,0,0,x
02/01/2002,Data,class2,4,10yo+,6,5,George Smith,1,2,0.5
02/01/2002,Data,class2,4,10yo+,6,3,Tom Phillips,0,0,x
02/01/2002,Data,class2,4,10yo+,6,1,Emma Lilly,0,1,0
02/01/2002,Data,class2,4,10yo+,6,6,George Smith,1,2,0.5
03/01/2002,Data,class3,4,10yo+,6,6,Ted James,0,1,0
03/01/2002,Data,class3,4,10yo+,6,3,Tom Phillips,0,3,0
03/01/2002,Data,class3,4,10yo+,6,2,George Smith,1,4,0.25
03/01/2002,Data,class3,4,10yo+,6,4,George Smith,1,4,0.25
03/01/2002,Data,class3,4,10yo+,6,1,George Smith,1,4,0.25
03/01/2002,Data,class3,4,10yo+,6,5,Tom Phillips,0,3,0
04/01/2002,Data,class4,2,10yo+,5,3,Emma Lilly,1,2,0.5
04/01/2002,Data,class4,2,10yo+,5,1,Ted James,0,2,0
04/01/2002,Data,class4,2,10yo+,5,2,George Smith,2,7,0.285714286
04/01/2002,Data,class4,2,10yo+,5,4,Emma Lilly,1,2,0.5
04/01/2002,Data,class4,2,10yo+,5,5,Tom Phillips,0,5,0
05/01/2002,Data,class5,4,11yo+,4,1,George Smith,2,8,0.25
05/01/2002,Data,class5,4,11yo+,4,2,Ted James,1,3,0.333333333
05/01/2002,Data,class5,4,11yo+,4,3,Emma Lilly,1,4,0.25
05/01/2002,Data,class5,4,11yo+,4,5,George Smith,2,8,0.25
06/01/2002,Data,class6,4,10yo+,6,4,Tom Phillips,0,6,0
06/01/2002,Data,class6,4,10yo+,6,2,Tom Phillips,0,6,0
06/01/2002,Data,class6,4,10yo+,6,5,George Smith,3,10,0.3
06/01/2002,Data,class6,4,10yo+,6,3,Tom Phillips,0,6,0
06/01/2002,Data,class6,4,10yo+,6,1,Emma Lilly,1,5,0.2
06/01/2002,Data,class6,4,10yo+,6,6,George Smith,3,10,0.3
07/01/2002,Data,class7,4,10yo+,6,6,Ted James,1,4,0.25
07/01/2002,Data,class7,4,10yo+,6,3,Tom Phillips,0,9,0
07/01/2002,Data,class7,4,10yo+,6,2,George Smith,3,12,0.25
07/01/2002,Data,class7,4,10yo+,6,4,George Smith,3,12,0.25
07/01/2002,Data,class7,4,10yo+,6,1,George Smith,3,12,0.25
07/01/2002,Data,class7,4,10yo+,6,5,Tom Phillips,0,9,0
08/01/2002,Data,class8,2,10yo+,5,3,Emma Lilly,2,6,0.333333333
08/01/2002,Data,class8,2,10yo+,5,1,Ted James,1,5,0.2
08/01/2002,Data,class8,2,10yo+,5,2,George Smith,4,15,0.266666667
08/01/2002,Data,class8,2,10yo+,5,4,Emma Lilly,2,6,0.333333333
08/01/2002,Data,class8,2,10yo+,5,5,Tom Phillips,0,11,0
09/01/2002,Data,class9,4,11yo+,4,1,George Smith,4,16,0.25
09/01/2002,Data,class9,4,11yo+,4,2,Ted James,2,6,0.333333333
09/01/2002,Data,class9,4,11yo+,4,3,Emma Lilly,2,8,0.25
09/01/2002,Data,class9,4,11yo+,4,5,George Smith,4,16,0.25
10/01/2002,Data,class10,4,10yo+,6,4,Tom Phillips,0,12,0
10/01/2002,Data,class10,4,10yo+,6,2,Tom Phillips,0,12,0
10/01/2002,Data,class10,4,10yo+,6,5,George Smith,5,18,0.277777778
10/01/2002,Data,class10,4,10yo+,6,3,Tom Phillips,0,12,0
10/01/2002,Data,class10,4,10yo+,6,1,Emma Lilly,2,9,0.222222222
10/01/2002,Data,class10,4,10yo+,6,6,George Smith,5,18,0.277777778
11/01/2002,Data,class11,4,10yo+,6,6,Ted James,2,7,0.285714286
11/01/2002,Data,class11,4,10yo+,6,3,Tom Phillips,0,15,0
11/01/2002,Data,class11,4,10yo+,6,2,George Smith,5,20,0.25
11/01/2002,Data,class11,4,10yo+,6,4,George Smith,5,20,0.25
11/01/2002,Data,class11,4,10yo+,6,1,George Smith,5,20,0.25
11/01/2002,Data,class11,4,10yo+,6,5,Tom Phillips,0,15,0
12/01/2002,Data,class12,2,10yo+,5,3,Emma Lilly,3,10,0.3
12/01/2002,Data,class12,2,10yo+,5,1,Ted James,2,8,0.25
12/01/2002,Data,class12,2,10yo+,5,2,George Smith,6,23,0.260869565
12/01/2002,Data,class12,2,10yo+,5,4,Emma Lilly,3,10,0.3
12/01/2002,Data,class12,2,10yo+,5,5,Tom Phillips,0,17,0
13/01/2002,Data,class13,4,11yo+,4,1,George Smith,6,24,0.25
13/01/2002,Data,class13,4,11yo+,4,2,Ted James,3,9,0.333333333
13/01/2002,Data,class13,4,11yo+,4,3,Emma Lilly,3,12,0.25
13/01/2002,Data,class13,4,11yo+,4,5,George Smith,6,24,0.25
14/01/2002,Data,class14,4,10yo+,6,4,Tom Phillips,0,18,0
14/01/2002,Data,class14,4,10yo+,6,2,Tom Phillips,0,18,0
14/01/2002,Data,class14,4,10yo+,6,5,George Smith,7,26,0.269230769
14/01/2002,Data,class14,4,10yo+,6,3,Tom Phillips,0,18,0
14/01/2002,Data,class14,4,10yo+,6,1,Emma Lilly,3,13,0.230769231
14/01/2002,Data,class14,4,10yo+,6,6,George Smith,7,26,0.269230769
15/01/2002,Data,class15,4,10yo+,6,6,Ted James,3,10,0.3
```

If anybody can help me achieve this I will truly grateful. If this requires more detail please ask.

One last note the csv in question has main data csv in question has 800k rows.

**EDIT**

Currently the output file appears as follows using the code supplied by @user650654:

```
data1,data2
```

If at all possible I would like the code changed slightly to out put two more things. Hopefully therse are not too difficult to do. Proposed changes to output file (commas represent each new row):

```
title row labeling the row (e.g. "x" or "0:0.05",Calculated avereage of values within each bracket e.g."0.02469",data1,data2
```

So in reality it would probably look like this:

```
x,n/a,data1,data2
0:0.05,0.02469,data1,data2
0.05:0.1,0.5469,data1,data2
....
....
```

Column1 = Row label (The data ranges that are being counted in the original question i.e. from 0 to 0.05
Column2 = Calculated average of values that fell within a particular range. I.e. If the 
Note the data1 & data2 are the two values the question innitially asked for.
Column1

Many thanks AEA

Comment: What have you got so far?  Do you know how to read a file?

Comment: "Calculated average of values in a particular range": is that the average of data1 values or is that the average of data2 values?  i.e. average of values where 7th column equals 1 or average of *all* values for that range?

Comment: Ahhh good point, the average of all the values in that range

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution for adding the two new fields:

```
import csv
import numpy


def count(infile='data.csv', outfile='new.csv'):
    bins = numpy.arange(0, 1.05, 0.05)

    total_x = 0
    col7one_x = 0

    total_zeros = 0
    col7one_zeros = 0

    all_array = []
    col7one_array = []

    with open(infile, 'r') as fobj:
        reader = csv.reader(fobj)
        for line in reader:
            if line[10] == 'x':
                total_x += 1
                if line[6] == '1':
                    col7one_x += 1
            elif line[10] == '0':
                # assumes zero is represented as "0" and not as say, "0.0"
                total_zeros += 1
                if line[6] == '1':
                    col7one_zeros += 1
            else:
                val = float(line[10])
                all_array.append(val)
                if line[6] == '1':
                    col7one_array.append(val)

    all_array = numpy.array(all_array)
    hist_all, edges = numpy.histogram(all_array, bins=bins)
    hist_col7one, edges = numpy.histogram(col7one_array, bins=bins)
    bin_ranges = ['%s:%s' % (x, y) for x, y in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])]

    digitized = numpy.digitize(all_array, bins)
    bin_means = [all_array[digitized == i].mean() if hist_all[i - 1] else 'n/a' for i in range(1, len(bins))]


    with open(outfile, 'w') as fobj:
        writer = csv.writer(fobj)
        writer.writerow(['x', 'n/a', col7one_x, total_x])
        writer.writerow(['0', 0 if total_zeros else 'n/a', col7one_zeros, total_zeros])
        for row in zip(bin_ranges, bin_means, hist_col7one, hist_all):
            writer.writerow(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    count()
```

Comment: Any chance of getting both scripts commented please, many thanks AEA

Comment: I realise there is no need to comment the other script but any comments you supply for this one will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey sorry to ask again, this code works perfectly but i could really use the comments to help me edit it.

Comment: Hi @user650654 thanks again for this code, I have awarded it the bounty, however I would really really appreciate some comments on the code to enable me to reverse engineer it more effectively. Many thanks AEA

Answer (score 3):

This might work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


column_names = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 
              'col7', 'col8', 'col9', 'col10', 'col11'] #names to be used as column labels.  If no names are specified then columns can be refereed to by number eg. df[0], df[1] etc.

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None, names=column_names) #header= None means there are no column headings in the  csv file

df.ix[df.col11 == 'x', 'col11']=-0.08 #trick so that 'x' rows will be grouped into a category >-0.1 and <= -0.05.  This will allow all of col11 to be treated as a numbers

bins = np.arange(-0.1, 1.0, 0.05) #bins to put col11 values in.  >-0.1 and <=-0.05 will be our special 'x' rows, >-0.05 and <=0 will capture all the '0' values.
labels = np.array(['%s:%s' % (x, y) for x, y in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])]) #create labels for the bins
labels[0] = 'x' #change first bin label to 'x'
labels[1] = '0' #change second bin label to '0'

df['col11'] = df['col11'].astype(float) #convert col11 to numbers so we can do math on them


df['bin'] = pd.cut(df['col11'], bins=bins, labels=False) # make another column 'bins' and put in an integer representing what bin the number falls into.Later we'll map the integer to the bin label


df.set_index('bin', inplace=True, drop=False, append=False) #groupby is meant to run faster with an index

def count_ones(x):
    """aggregate function to count values that equal 1"""
    return np.sum(x==1)

dfg = df[['bin','col7','col11']].groupby('bin').agg({'col11': [np.mean], 'col7': [count_ones, len]}) # groupby the bin number and apply aggregate functions to specified column.
dfg.index = labels[dfg.index]# apply labels to bin numbers

dfg.ix['x',('col11', 'mean')]='N/A' #mean of 'x' rows is meaningless
print(dfg)
dfg.to_csv('new.csv')
```

which gave me

```
                col7           col11
          count_ones  len       mean
x                  1    7        N/A
0                  2   21          0
0.15:0.2           2    2        0.2
0.2:0.25           9   22  0.2478632
0.25:0.3           0   13  0.2840755
0.3:0.35           0    5  0.3333333
0.45:0.5           0    4        0.5
```

Comment: Hey rtrwalker this code is really nice. I was wondering If you could comment it further. I havn't used pandas as of yet, and have been trying my best to manipulate and add to this code. But to no avail. I have been watching videos on youtube to try to get to grips with it. I think it is the `bins` and uses of `zip` which is really throwing me.

Comment: Whilst I had already awarded the bounty I will probably mark this as the accepted answer If I can understand it a little better. The line I am struggling with the most is `dfg = df[['bin','col7','col11']].groupby('bin').agg({'col11': [np.mean], 'col7': [count_ones, len]})`

Comment: In fact if this can be done I will gladly assign you the same bounty of 50 points for the time taken!

Comment: Apparently a second bounty on a question has to be twice as much so it would be 100 point bounty

Comment: I have opened up a whole question with 100 point bounty on it dedicated to trying to understand this pandas code you have provided. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748000/understanding-this-pandas-script

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `numpy.histogram`.  See below.

```
import csv
import numpy


def count(infile='data.csv', outfile='new.csv'):
    total_x = 0
    col7one_x = 0
    total_zeros = 0
    col7one_zeros = 0
    all_array = []
    col7one_array = []
    with open(infile, 'r') as fobj:
        reader = csv.reader(fobj)
        for line in reader:
            if line[10] == 'x':
                total_x += 1
                if line[6] == '1':
                    col7one_x += 1
            elif line[10] == '0':
                # assumes zero is represented as "0" and not as say, "0.0"
                total_zeros += 1
                if line[6] == '1':
                    col7one_zeros += 1
            else:
                val = float(line[10])
                all_array.append(val)
                if line[6] == '1':
                    col7one_array.append(val)

    bins = numpy.arange(0, 1.05, 0.05)
    hist_all, edges = numpy.histogram(all_array, bins=bins)
    hist_col7one, edges = numpy.histogram(col7one_array, bins=bins)

    with open(outfile, 'w') as fobj:
        writer = csv.writer(fobj)
        writer.writerow([col7one_x, total_x])
        writer.writerow([col7one_zeros, total_zeros])
        for row in zip(hist_col7one, hist_all):
            writer.writerow(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    count()
```

Comment: Hey nice answer, any chance of getting this commented? Many thanks :)

Comment: Hello the answer certainly works however the output has spaces between the new lines.

Comment: added some more detail and a bounty to the question.

Comment: Any chance of getting both scripts commented please, many thanks AEA