# Understanding this Pandas script

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, comments

I received this code to group data into a histogram type data. I have been Attempting to understand the code in this pandas script in order to edit, manipulate and duplicate it. I have comments for the sections I understand.

#### Code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


column_names = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 
              'col7', 'col8', 'col9', 'col10', 'col11'] #names to be used as column labels.  If no names are specified then columns can be refereed to by number eg. df[0], df[1] etc.

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None, names=column_names) #header= None means there are no column headings in the  csv file

df.ix[df.col11 == 'x', 'col11']=-0.08 #trick so that 'x' rows will be grouped into a category >-0.1 and <= -0.05.  This will allow all of col11 to be treated as a numbers

bins = np.arange(-0.1, 1.0, 0.05) #bins to put col11 values in.  >-0.1 and <=-0.05 will be our special 'x' rows, >-0.05 and <=0 will capture all the '0' values.
labels = np.array(['%s:%s' % (x, y) for x, y in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])]) #create labels for the bins
labels[0] = 'x' #change first bin label to 'x'
labels[1] = '0' #change second bin label to '0'

df['col11'] = df['col11'].astype(float) #convert col11 to numbers so we can do math on them


df['bin'] = pd.cut(df['col11'], bins=bins, labels=False) # make another column 'bins' and put in an integer representing what bin the number falls into.Later we'll map the integer to the bin label


df.set_index('bin', inplace=True, drop=False, append=False) #groupby is meant to run faster with an index

def count_ones(x):
    """aggregate function to count values that equal 1"""
    return np.sum(x==1)

dfg = df[['bin','col7','col11']].groupby('bin').agg({'col11': [np.mean], 'col7': [count_ones, len]})
dfg.index = labels[dfg.index]

dfg.ix['x',('col11', 'mean')]='N/A'
print(dfg)
dfg.to_csv('new.csv')
```

The section I really struggle to understand is in this section:

```
def count_ones(x):
    """aggregate function to count values that equal 1"""
    return np.sum(x==1)

dfg = df[['bin','col7','col11']].groupby('bin').agg({'col11': [np.mean], 'col7': [count_ones, len]})
dfg.index = labels[dfg.index]

dfg.ix['x',('col11', 'mean')]='N/A'
print(dfg)
dfg.to_csv('new.csv')
```

If any one is able to comment this script I would be greatly appreciative. Also feel free to correct or add to my comments (these are what I assume so far they may not be correct). Im hoping this isnt too off topic for SOF. I will gladly give a 50 point bounty to any user who can help me with this.

Comment: Read agg function documentation as a first step

Comment: thanks will do, I spent my time watching pandas tutorial videos thus far.

Comment: I believe this is the documentation he is referring too. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html I am afraid I cant help with the comments this code is beyond me for now.

Comment: @Boud was there anything in the original comments that is incorrect? (just in case i'm being lead a merry dance)

Comment: Thanks @GTPE on that documentation now.

Comment: Good advice here is to run it line by line, and inspect each variable as you go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll try and explain my code. As it uses a few tricks.

- I've called it `df` to give a shorthand name for a pandas DataFrame
- I've called it `dfg` to mean group my `df`.
- Let me build up the expression `dfg = df[['bin','col7','col11']].groupby('bin').agg({'col11': [np.mean], 'col7': [count_ones, len]})`

  - the code `dfg = df[['bin','col7','col11']]` is saying take the columns named 'bin' 'col7' and 'col11' from my DataFrame `df`.
  - Now that I have the 3 columns I am interested in, I want to group by the values in the 'bin' column.  This is done by `dfg = df[['bin','col7','col11']].groupby('bin')`.  I now have groups of data i.e. all records that are in bin #1, all records in bin#2, etc.
  - I now want to apply some aggregate functions to the records in each of my bin groups(  An aggregate funcitn is something like sum, mean or count).
  - Now I want to apply three aggregate functions to the records in each of my bins: the mean of 'col11', the number of records in each bin, and the number of records in each bin that have 'col7' equal to one.   The mean is easy; numpy already has a function to calculate the mean. If I was just doing the mean of 'col11' I would write:  `dfg = df[['bin','col7','col11']].groupby('bin').agg({'col11': [np.mean]})`.  The number of records is also easy; python's `len` function (It's not really a function but  a property of lists etc.) will give us the number of items in list.  So I now have `dfg = df[['bin','col7','col11']].groupby('bin').agg({'col11': [np.mean], 'col7': [len]})`.  Now I can't think of an existing function that counts the number of ones in a numpy array (it has to work on a numpy array).  I can define my own functions that work on a numpy array, hence my function `count_ones`.
  - Now I'll deconstruct the `count_ones` function.  the varibale `x` passed to the function is always going to be a 1d numpy array.  In our specific case it will be all the 'col7' values that fall in bin#1, all the 'col7' values that fall in bin#2 etc.. The code `x==1` will create a boolean (TRUE/FALSE) array the same size as x.  The entries in the boolean array will be True if the corresponding values in x are equal to 1 and false otherwise.  Because python treats True as 1 if I sum the values of my boolean array I'll get a count of the values that ==1.  Now that I have my `count_ones` function I apply it to 'col7' by: `dfg = df[['bin','col7','col11']].groupby('bin').agg({'col11': [np.mean], 'col7': [count_ones, len]})`
  - You can see that the syntax of the `.agg` is `.agg({'column_name_to_apply_to': [list_of_function names_to_apply]}`
  - With the boolean arrays you can do all sorts of wierd condition combinations (x==6) | (x==3) would be 'x equal to 6 or x equal to 3'.  The 'and' operator is &.  Always put `()` around each condition
- Now to `dfg.index = labels[dfg.index]`.  In `dfg`, because I grouped by 'bin', the index (or row label) of each row of grouped data (i.e. my dfg.index) will be my bin numbers:1,2,3,  `labels[dfg.index]` is using fancy indexing of a numpy array.  labels[0] would give me the first label, labels[3] would give me the 4th label.  With normal python lists you can use slices to do labels[0:3] which would give me labels 0,1, and 2. With numpy arrays we can go a step further and just index with  a list of values or another array so labels[np.array([0,2,4]) would give me labels 0,2,4.  By using `labels[dfg.index]` I'm requesting the labels corresponding to the bin#.  Basically I'm changng my bin number to bin label.  I could have done that to my original data but that would be thousands of rows; by doing it after the group by I'm doing it to 21 rows or so.  Note that I cannot just do `dfg.index = labels` as some of my bins might be empty and therefore not present in the group by data.
- Now the `dfg.ix['x',('col11', 'mean')]='N/A'` part.  Remember way back when I did `df.ix[df.col11 == 'x', 'col11']=-0.08` that was so all my invalid data was treated as a number and would be placed into the 1st bin.  after applying group by and aggregate functions the mean of 'col11' values in my first bin will be -0.08 (because all such values are -0.08).  Now I know this not correct, all values of -0.08 actually indicate that the original value wsa x.  You can't do a mean of x.  So I manually put it to N/A. ie. `dfg.ix['x',('col11', 'mean')]='N/A'` means in dfg where index (or row) is 'x' and column is 'col11 mean') set the value to 'N/A'.  the `('col11', 'mean')` I believe is how pandas comes up with the aggreagate column names i.e. when I did `.agg({'col11': [np.mean]})`, to refer to the resulting aggregate column i need `('column_name', 'aggregate_function_name')`

The motivation for all this was: convert all data to numbers so I can use the power of Pandas, then after processing,  manually change any values that I know are garbage.  Let me know if you need any more explanation.

Comment: First up 1 million thanks for the explanation. Just reading now :)

Comment: I found this tutorial very useful in figuring out my answer http://www.bearrelroll.com/2013/05/python-pandas-tutorial/